# 403 Forbidden error (specific to one directory) Apache

Tags: permissions, apache2

Currently have multiple websites on one server (EC2, Ubunutu, Apache). Very simple static sites that are simply displaying text, css, and images. My issue is that I made a new site locally and uploaded all the files at once through SFTP (filezilla) and all the text, font awesome icons (installed locally), and CSS renders through the browser, however, all of the images are receiving a 403 error.

Figuring it is permission specific I have tried leveraging the `chmod` command to reset specific permission sets of the folder `/var/www/vhosts/sitename/images`, specific images `/var/www/vhosts/sitename/images/image01.jpg`, as well as the site folder itself but to no luck.

Currently the `images` folder has the following permissions `drw-rwSrw-`. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To your site conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ add to the directory settings:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nadav! However, I found out that I needed to specify a directory for the `AllowOverride` command as I was unable to restart Apache without doing so. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ok good luck with your project